# How to list all older versions of Grails plugins?

Tags: grails, version, grails-plugin

The [Grails Plugins site](http://grails.org/plugins/) only seems to list the latest versions of all the Grails plugins. But what if I wanted to see a list of other available (older) versions for each plugin? Is there a Grails SDK command/target I can issue to see old plugins?

I ask because I'm using a plugin whose current latest release is broke and its version is "2.0-RC2". Since it's a release candidate, I'd like to know what the last **stable** (non-RC) version is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such command to see old plugins.

If you are referring to Spring Security Core plugin then corresponding github repository has two branches:

[<kbd>**master**</kbd>](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core) referring to 2.0-RC2 and [<kbd>**1.x**</kbd>](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tree/1.x) referring to the last stable release 1.2.7.3.

On a side note, if you want to see all installed plugins with their versions then below command can be issued:

```
grails list-plugins --installed
```

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro (+1) - but how did you know that the last stable release is 1.2.7.3? That version number doesn't appear anywhere on the `1.x` link you provided!

Comment: Every grails plugin comes with a [plugin descriptor](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/1.x/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy#L117) which provides the version of the plugin.

Answer (score 5):

You can see the plugins at the main repo site [here](http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/). The site is referenced via `grailsCentral()` in the `BuildConfig.groovy` file which in turn references the repo site in the `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.maven.aether.config.RepositoriesConfiguration.groovy` file